# Javascript onchange not working anymore after upload on public_html

Tags: javascript

**What I want to do**

Auto populate a form text field based on what is selected in a form select field.

**What I have done so far**

The code below is working perfectly fine during development:

STEP 1: I populate array of data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var carcolorData = new Array();
carcolorData['Ford'] = 'Blue';
carcolorData['BMW'] = 'Green';
carcolorData['Fiat'] = 'Red';
carcolorData[''] = 'Hello';
</script>
```

STEP 2: I create a typical html form with a text and select field:

```
<form>    
<select name="cartype" id="cartype" >
<option selected="selected"></option>
<option>Ford</option>
<option>BMW</option>
<option>Fiat</option>
</select>

<input name="carcolor" type="text" id="carcolor" />
</form>
```

STEP 3: I create a little javascript function to autopopulate onchange:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.form.cartype.onchange = showColor;
function showColor() 
{
var obj_sel = document.form.cartype;
document.form.carcolor.value = carcolorData[obj_sel.value];
}
</script>
```

**The problem**

Doesn't work anymore after upload on public_html. Whatever I select it displays 'Hello' which is the color corresponding to blank in my example. I am totally lost... The code is correct since it works fine during development phase. Why is it not working anymore after upload on public_html?

**Possible reasons**

I am thinking of this but I may be far from the truth...

1. Different versions of IE (?)
2. Different development parameters (?)
3. Conflict with other javascript on the same page (?)
4. The javascript is not positioned correctly in the script (?)

Comment: Isn't it because you do not wait for the document ready event before setting the onchange handler? (wild guess)

Comment: Hi Baszz, I put the onchange javascript just after my form, I mean after </form>. Is it correct?

Comment: It should be. Maybe it's better to place the code in the window.onload=function(){} method.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
document.forms
```

not document.form

To get the select "cartype", assume you got only one form, use:

```
document.forms[0].cartype
```

Also, are you missing the <form tag before the <select?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.form.cartype.onchange = showColor;
function showColor() 
{
var obj_sel = document.form.cartype;
document.form.carcolor.value = carcolorData[obj_sel.value];
}
</script>
```

To this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var showColor = function ()
            {
                var myform = document.form; //maybe change this to match form with an id.
                var selected_cartype = myform.cartype.options[myform.cartype.selectedIndex].value; //better do this to get a select value
                myform.carcolor.value = carcolorData[selected_cartype];
            }
        document.form.cartype.onchange = showColor;
    </script>
```

And there is another problem in the HTML : select's options have no value attribute.

```
<select name="cartype" id="cartype" >
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option>Ford</option>
    <option>BMW</option>
    <option>Fiat</option>
</select>
```

To

```
<select name="cartype" id="cartype" >
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    <option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi Olivier, Thanks for your answer but I believe your script will write in the carcolor field the name of the car. What I want is write in the carcolor field the color of the car based on the car selected. For that I have to pick the color in the carcolorData array. How to modify your script to do that? Thanks.

Comment: I edited it, sorry I missed this part ! I changed `myform.carcolor.value = selected_cartype;` to `myform.carcolor.value = carcolorData[selected_cartype];`

Comment: Hi Olivier, I have tried your code but I was unfortunately not been able to make it work... The good news is that I found a fix to my problem. So I explain for future viewers: seems that the problem came from browser. I developped on IE9, I tested on IE7. For some strange reason my script was not able to recognize the cartype selected. What I did is that I added the following code to the select box: <option value="Ford">Ford</option>. After I do that it works. It is not such a nice looking fix but it works :-)

Comment: Of course it can't work : the value attribute is what we try to get with this javascript. If options has no attribute value, we will always get an undefined. This is not a browser issue : the HTML is not correct. I've edited my answer with this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But correctly if I am wrong in IE9 browser it looks like you do not need to indicate value. The browser will pick as value the text between ><. I have tried it and it works.

Comment: Yes, but all browsers do not handle it this way. That's why you got different behaviours depending of the browser.